# shortcut to put monitors to sleep

Tags: windows-7, display, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn off display in Windows 7 without additional software](https://superuser.com/questions/321342/turn-off-display-in-windows-7-without-additional-software)

I have windows 7 installed with two monitors connected to it.

I want to create a shortcut that will put both of my monitors to sleep.
not  to put the entire computer to sleep, just the monitors. is that possible ?!

thanks

kfir

Comment: How about engaging the screensaver like this thread says? 
http://superuser.com/questions/344177/whats-the-fastest-way-to-trigger-your-screensaver-windows-7/344180#344180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For standbying the 2 monitors i am now using the progam "LCDoff" , I was using "monitoroff", both are very tiny utilities.
http://www.kev009.com/wp/projects/lcdoff/
I made a shortcut to it, and it works. One time a video playback program was running that disables monitor standby, other than that, it is working. Moving the mouse, or using the keyboard wakes it back up, so I assume it is triggering windows own standby routine.

Answer (score 5):

Engaging the screen saver doesn't turn off the monitor. Also, using the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> doesn't either, it only locks it.

So, you could try a utility at NirSoft called [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) which will do what you need, as well as many other things. You will just need to set up a short cut to the command needed and you are set.

If you need step by step instructions, go [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-turn-off-the-monitor/) for that.