# How to lock Windows 7 session with just key strokes?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, workstation

I could lock my Windows XP workstation using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>. That keystroke combination does not work on Windows 7. Is there a method of locking Windows 7 using just keystrokes?

Comment: Related: [What's the fastest way to trigger your screensaver?](http://superuser.com/q/344177/354511)

Comment: it's strange finding people using ctrl+alt+del to lock or open task manager nowadays even in Windows 10

Answer (score 127, accepted):

<kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> should do what you need.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this isn't a new shortcut to Windows 7... it has been around since at least the XP days. Check out the "Windows key" Wikipedia page for other useful shortucts that use this key: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key

Comment: My habit: try *every* `Windows key` + letter combination and see what they do whenever a new Windows version is released.

Comment: @Alvin and not only letter: the win+arrowkey have nice features too.

Comment: Win+M (or Win+D), Win+L, and Win+R are the big three for me *(Also Win-P, when I used to have a laptop)*

Comment: @AlvinWong , you can also check [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) or [here for Win8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/new-keyboard-shortcuts#1TC=t1) for a complete list, or in the Windows manual (printed or online). Should be easier than _trying_.

Comment: @AlvinWong yeah, I only said it was easier ;-)

Comment: Uh-oh. My windows key is not working. This post is rubbing salt in my long-forgotten wounds.

Comment: @AnuragKalia Windows key can be replaced by Ctrl+Esc. Unfortunately I haven't find a way to replace Windows in a compound key, except remapping the keys

Answer (score 16):

Use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. If you use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) you can reprogram <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to do other things too, like lock your session, and also wait 10 seconds and put monitors to sleep. Powerful little hotkey program.

Answer (score 12):

Also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>**,** <kbd>Enter</kbd>   and   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>**,** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> seem to work for me.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Del Enter is the way. This has worked across various versions of Windows for a long time, since the default button on the Ctrl-Alt-Del screen is "Lock this computer".

Comment: Also Space instead of Enter works as well, since it's the default highlighted item.

Comment: Wouldn't Ctrl+Alt+Del Alt+K depend on one's installed/selected language variant, though?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: (1) Good point.  I hadn’t consciously considered that.  You are probably right.  (2) I’ll fall back on @Kaz and @Viper’s suggestions that (Enter) and (Space) are the universal answers.  (3) Since the OP said that `K` worked for him on Windows XP, I believe that it’s quite likely that ***he*** is an English user.

Comment: @Kaz: and `Windows+L` hasn't worked for a long time across Windows versions? Don't remember about Windows 2000, but at least since XP this worked fine.

Comment: -1 for unnecessarily involved way to do it. Surprised you didn't know Windows + L.

Comment: @Austin''Danger''Powers: Gosh.  (1) The OP seemed to be interested in (Ctrl+Alt+Del) + K solutions.  (2) Trey had already answered (Windows+L) by the time I answered.  And (3) I ***did*** know about (Win+L) before I read Trey’s answer; but see (1).

Comment: 4 keystrokes vs 2 keystrokes. These are SHORTcuts we're talking about here. Key combinations that make doing routine tasks quick, easy, and effortless. Windows + L is also much easier to remember for non techie types.

Answer (score 5):

You can even use a simple batch file. Just double click on it & your PC will get locked.
Just copy & paste the below code in to Notepad & save it as (for example) "lock.bat".
That's it - you're done, just double click on it.

The code is:

```
@echo off
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
cls
```

Comment: This is over-involved and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't use rundll32 on things that weren't made for rundll32 (and those are deprecated since Vista) See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx (Sadly down at the moment)

Comment: @AlexBrault Working fine for me now.

Comment: If you put this file on your Desktop and assign a Shortcut key (combination) to it, then that keystroke combination will lock the workstation.  It must be Ctrl+Alt+(something) or Ctrl+Shift+Alt+(something).  You might need to logout and login again before it becomes effective.

Comment: This code is great when you are trying to plug this into a macro key on your keyboard. Thanks Sunil.

Comment: create a link/shortcut with the command, no need to turn echo off or clear screen, and assign a shortcut key to that shortcut. Now you have a shortcut to do whatever you want

Comment: @3Doubloons' link is still broken but you can read the blog post at https://web.archive.org/web/20151205153714/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx

Comment: The updated link is https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043 (Though there are no comments and they are closed so there's no real difference from the archive) That said, 7 years later, I'm not sure why I linked that article and not this one: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643 (Probably because the former explicitly calls out LockWorkStation as a bad idea)